# How do you flatten a nested List using round robin in Scala?

Tags: scala

How would you flatten this List in Scala: `List(List(1, 2, 3), Nil, List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8))` so that it does a round-robin and not just append all elements like `flatMap` would do? Desired outcome is: `List(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6)`

Unlike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581192) my list is of single type `List[List[Int]]` but it looks like I can also use recursive function calls.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening nested lists of the same type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581192/flattening-nested-lists-of-the-same-type)

Comment: This would be dead easy if it was a matrix, aka all nested lists had the same length... `l.transpose.flatten`

Comment: @dcastro: What does `transpose` do, take minimum width and height?

Comment: @Bergi it rotates a matrix. So, `List(List(1,2,3), List(4,5,6))` becomes `List(List(1,4), List(2,5), List(3, 6))`

Comment: @dcastro: Yeah, exactly, but what happens when the inner lists are not of the same length? Cut them off?

Comment: @Bergi throws an exception. Thats why we can't use transpose here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Flatten the list while matching each element with its index in the nested list
2. Sort by their index in the nested list
3. Map the tuples into integers

   ```
   list.flatMap(xs => xs.zipWithIndex).sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)

   //output 
   List(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a homework assignment, you need to mark it as such.

```
def roundRobin(input: List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
  val m = input.filter(_.size > 0)
  if ( m.size > 0 ) 
    m map (mh => mh.head) ::: roundRobin(m map (mt => mt.tail)))
  else
    Nil
}
```

First, collect the non-empty lists. If there are none, we are finished. Otherwise, collect the heads of each remaining list, and concatenate to the roundRobin-processed tails.

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive approach,

```
def g(xs:List[List[Int]]): List[Int] = {
  if (xs.flatten.isEmpty) 
    Nil 
  else 
    xs.flatMap(_.take(1)) ++ g(xs.map(_.drop(1)))
}
```

Hence

```
g(List(List(1, 2, 3), List(), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8)))
List(1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 8, 3, 6)
```

and

```
g(List(Nil))
List()
```